# Email results of ansible playbook / shell command?

Tags: linux, ansible

I am looking to email the results of an ansible playbook

I am using debug: var=results.stdout_lines to display the stdout of a shell command but I want to then bundle that up and email it to myself.

I feel like there has to be a built in way to do this, but I can't find anything?

My playbook looks like

```
- name: run command
      shell: echo `hostname`
      register: results
      when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"

    - debug: var=results.stdout_lines
```

which will print the stdout results of the command during the playbook run, but i want to then email that to myself.

I tried emailing the registered variable 'results' but it fails

```
- local_action: mail
                subject='Maricache backup report'
                body={{ results.stdout_lines }}
                to='partytime@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it, found the solution somewhere and it worked for me also.

```
- name: logs result
  shell: grep "`date '+%b.%d'`" /var/log/commands.log
  register: command_log

- name: mail result
  mail:
    to: helloworld@xyz.com
    subject: "command logs for today"
    body: "{{ command_log.stdout }}"
  when: command_log.stdout
```